# How to use IO.File AppendAllLines

Tags: .net, powershell

```
$text = "Hello","World"
[IO.File]::AppendAllLines(
    "C:\test.txt", 
    $text, 
    [Text.Encoding]::Default
)
```

And i get error:

```
'Cannot find an overload for "AppendAllLines" and the argument count: "3".'
```

How to fix it? WriteAllLines works great with same parameters, but what's wrong with this method?

Comment: Why use that instead of `>>` with a multiline string? Or Add-Content?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Whenever I choose .NET methods over PS built-ins it's mostly for performance, sometimes additional functionality.

Comment: @marsze in this case they do the same things. As for performance, each step in a Powershell pipeline runs on its own thread. If you loop in Powershell, execution will be slow. If you create a pipeline, it will be a *lot* faster

Comment: @marsze in this case, appending lines as they become available from previous steps means the script won't have to wait for everything to finish before appending the results.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was just making a general comment. I am not the OP. As for performance, there are a lot of variations, so it's very different in every case. Best is always to simply test it. I remember a good talk by Don Jones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell has trouble with `$text` because the type is `object[]` but the method expects a string-enumerable.

Cast it to `string[]` first:

```bsh
[string[]]$text = "Hello","World"

# or

[IO.File]::AppendAllLines(
    "C:\test.txt",
    [string[]]$text, 
    [Text.Encoding]::Default
)
```

Comment: I thought, that (str , str) automatically is array of strings. Thanks.

Comment: @Danny By default, every array in Powershell is `object[]`